# creating map from json string yields TypeError: JSON.parse(...) is not iterable

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a js map from a json string like this:

```
function jsonToMap(jsonStr) 
{
    return new Map(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
}
```

The jsonStr parameter contains a valid json. The json has only string keys but can have objects as values.

Invoking the method above yields the error

> TypeError: JSON.parse(...) is not iterable

Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you add a sample JSON to the question?

Comment: this is an exmaple of a json: `{"key" : "value"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tells us that the outermost part of what the JSON defines is not iterable. For instance, perhaps it defines an object (plain objects are not iterable).

If it does define an object and you want to get a `Map` for it, you can do that via [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
function jsonToMap(jsonStr) 
{
    return new Map(Object.entries(JSON.parse(jsonStr)));
}
```

`Object.entries` creates an array of `[name, value]` pairs for the own, enumerable, string-named properties of an object.

Comment: The json is indeed inside object notation. that was it